# Select one out of 2 specific files, copy and rename it

Tags: scripting, find, ios

I need help running code locally using a terminal app called NewTerm2 on my iPhone (this app has limited functionality but it's more comfortable with unix commands)

Here's the case:

I have this tree `/Library/Themes/"Variable Folder"/Bundles/com.apple.springboard/some images.png` (Variable Folder can be any name)

Variable Folders might contain several images but the ones I'm interested in are only Image1 or Image2, **to be clear, some could contain only one of these 2**

I need to:

1- copy one of the 2 patterns only, "Image1.png" or "Image2.png"

2- rename the copied image "Variable Folder.png" and place it in another location.

So I started with this code applying to Image1

`cd /Library/Themes/"Variable Folder"/Bundles/com.apple.springboard`

`cp "Image1.png" /var/mobile/Documents/Dock-Temp/"Variable Folder.png"`

But it worked only for the Variable folders containing Image1, so I modified it to this:

`cd /Library/Themes/"Variable Folder"/Bundles/com.apple.springboard`

`find . -type f \( -name "Image1.png" -or -name "Image2.png" \) | head -n 1 | sed 's|^./||' | xargs cp /var/mobile/Documents/Dock-Temp/"Variable Folder.png"`

`head -n 1` gets the first result from find, `sed 's|^./||'` removes ./ before file name

But only the part of code up to xargs works, I'd be grateful if someone helps me find the error

Comment: "on the part of code upto xargs works". What about it doesn't work? Do you see an error message, or does it just exit?

Comment: How about `cp $(ls Image?.png | head -n 1) /var/mobile/Documents/Dock-Temp/"Variable Folder.png"`

Comment: @pxeger it says cp cannot stat /var/mobile/Documents/Dock-Temp/"Variable Folder.png": no such file or directory

Comment: Does the directory `/var/mobile/Documents/Dock-Temp/` exist? If not, create it

Comment: @Philippos" ls Image?.png" is a kind of wildcard but not applicable as there are no real Image1 or 2 in my actual code, they are called SBDock@2x.png and SBDock@3x.png but there are also SBDock@2x~iphone.png etc. So if SBDock@2x.png is missing I would like cp to pick SBDock@3x.png but in alphabetical order SBDock@2x~iphone.png will appear before SBDock@3x.png

Comment: @pxeger Yes it exists

Comment: I suspect that cp is missing an option that prevents it to read xargs

Comment: Try `find . -type f \( -name "Image1.png" -or -name "Image2.png" \) | head -n 1 | sed 's|^./||' | xargs -I % cp % /var/mobile/Documents/Dock-Temp/"Variable Folder.png"`

Comment: @pxeger Thank you very much, it works :)